# Search Activity listview' s onitemclicklistener showing different information than expected

Tags: android, listview, search, parse-platform, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview in activityA where 1st listem is test heading 1, 2nd item is test heading 2, from 3rd list item it is list heading 8, list heading 9, so on like in the image below

[image]

[image]

Now i have a button in activity A which opens up new activity i.e search activity which searches user input from the list in activity A [image]

Till here everything works fine but i face problem in adding onitemclicklistener in searchactivity

The problem is::

For example if user searches for list in editext of search activity the searc results are shown with list item containing word list i.e

list heading 8
list heading 9
list heading 10
list heading 11
And so on....
And if user clicks list heading 8 item it should open singleitem view and data corresponding to list heading 8 as it would show in activity A but it shows the data belonging to 1st list item of activity A and so on in search activity

How should it diplay correct singleitem view data to correct list item shown in search results of search activity

**my search activity**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

protected  EditText searchedittext;
ImageButton searchButton;
List<ParseObject> ob;
List<CodeList> codelist = null;
FinalAdapter fnladapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

    searchedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_layoutEditText);

    final ListView searchedlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
    searchedlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    searchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchlayoutbtn);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String seaechedit = searchedittext.getText().toString();

                if(seaechedit.isEmpty()){

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER SOME SEARCH QUERY")
                        .setTitle("EMPTY SEARCH") 
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }
                else{
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
                    // InterActivity7 is the class name in parse database where listview retrives it data from
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "InterActivity");

                    query.whereContains("listheading", seaechedit);
                    query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
                    query.setLimit(200);

                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> p1, ParseException e)
                            {
                                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                                if(e == null){

                                    ob = p1;

                                    String [] searchHeadings = new String[ob.size()];

                                    int i = 0;

                                    // listheading is the coloumn name in parse database
                                    for(ParseObject heading : ob){ searchHeadings[i] = (String) heading.get("listheading");
                                        i++;

                                    }

                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchHeadings );
                                    searchedlist.setAdapter(adapter);


                                }else{

                                    Log.e("searchactivity", e.getMessage()); 
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this); 
                                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()) 
                                        .setTitle("Nothing found")
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null); 
                                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                    dialog.show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }


            }

        });

}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();



    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");

            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {


                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        fnladapter = new FinalAdapter(SearchActivity.this,
                                      codelist);

    }

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int position, long p4)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) fnladapter.getItem(position);


    try{

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);

        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(codes);



        intent.putExtra("intro",
                        (codelist.get(position).getIntroduction()));



        // Start SingleItemView Class
        //   startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        //something went w3ong
    }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of position use id to fetch data

Change

```
CodeList codes = (CodeList) fnladapter.getItem(position);

to
CodeList codes = (CodeList) fnladapter.getItem((int)p4);
```

Comment: fnladapter.getitem() only takes int not long

Comment: You can convert long to int. But the question is how you are storing  the data if you are using id to manage the data then only my answer will work

Comment: ya that is only my problem

Comment: so all the best. Please accept my answer if it works.i also updated my answer to support int